# Assistance needed in understanding a Python script

Tags: android, python, repository

I am analyzing the repo script from Google (instructions at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

The repo script is written in Python.  There is a part in there that says:

```
if sys.argv[-1] =='#%s' % magic
```

Can somebody explain semantically what that line means?  I am a bit rusty on my Python.  The entire block of code for this is:

```
magic='--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--'
"""exec" python -E "$0" "$@" """#$magic"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.argv[-1] =='#%s' % magic:
        del sys.argv[-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One piece at the time:

- [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.argv) holds *the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.* Meaning that `sys-argv[-1]` is the last argument.
- `'#%s' % magic`. The `%` formats your string, which means the where you see `%s` there's going to be the value of `magic` (if `magic` is not a string it will be converted: `str(magic)`). In your code that string is going to be: `'#--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--'`.
- `del sys.argv[-1]`. This is self-explainatory: means that the last value of the list `sys.argv` is going to be removed.

All together it means that: **if the last command line argument is `#--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--` that argument is going to be removed from `sys.argv`.**

Answer (score 1):

It formats magic as a string in the format '#nnn' where n is `magic` converted to a string and compares the string with the last argument passed on the command line (negative indexes index the list from its end). If found, the arg is removed from the list of arguments.

Comment: What do you mean "magic number"?  I don't see anything math-related in this script...

Comment: @Igor G, the value of `$magic` and `magic`. I probably should have code formatted it to be more clear. It need not be a number, I think "number" just slipped in there by mistake because of the common usage of "magic numbers" as well as the # symbol.